# `Serial` attribute missing with the pyserial library (ubuntu 16.04 with python 2.7)

Tags: python, pyserial

```
import serial 

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", baudrate = 9600, timeout=1)

while 1:

    Data = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
print(Data)
```

Error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'

Comment: After importing, have you verified that `serial` is what you're expecting? Does `dir(serial)` return what you're expecting (is `Serial` present)? What does `serial.Serial` return?

Comment: yes i did i am getting the correct output at the port....

Comment: i don't know y i still getting that error

Answer (score 0):

You're importing the module, not the class. So, you have to use:

```
from serial import serial
```